# GCP API - OAuth 2.0 from Postman

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, postman, google-oauth

I have developed an Python webapp on GCP App Engine.
I want to use OAuth 2.0 client ID as an authentication for my app.
In `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials` there is an OAuth 2.0 client ID with my app URL added as `Authorized redirect URIs`.
My Postman access token configuration looks like the following:
[image]

And authorization configuration:
[image]

Despite that I am getting following response: `Status: 401 Unauthorized`
Info from the header: `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer, error="invalid_token"`
Response body:

```
{
 "code": 16,
 "message": "JWT validation failed: Bad JWT format: Invalid JSON in header",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "auth"
  }
 ]
}
```

What I am doing wrong? How should I troubleshoot this?

---

EDIT: Adding request

```
POST /parse HTTP/1.1
Host: [my_app_name].appspot.com
Content-length: 0
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [token_generated_by_postman]
```

Comment: Show the request that is generated.

Comment: @JohnHanley Added request in edit

Comment: You are showing the wrong flow. Show the HTTP Request for getting the OAuth Token.